# NLog use Connection String Name in appsettings

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, nlog

I have an NLog database target that looks like this:

```
<target xsi:type="Database" name="database"
      connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ApplicationOne;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=User0101;Password=PW0101"   
      commandText="INSERT INTO [SchemaOne].[EventLogs](Id, Message, Level, Logger )VALUES(NewID(), @Message, @Level, @Logger)">
  <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
  <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
</target>
```

Is it possible to change the connectionString to use connectionStringName from my appsettings instead?

My appsettings is called dssettings.json and it contains the connection details here:

```
"DatabaseConfiguration": {
    "DatabaseName": "ApplicationOne",
    "ConnectionName": "DefaultConnection",
    "ConnectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ApplicationOne;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=User0101;Password=PW0101" 
  },
```

Comment: You shouldn't store the connection string in neither one, its not secure and you could accidentally commit it into your source control management system (Git, CSV etc.). Use [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows), environment variables or [azure key value store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I understand but this is for a small project that has been using appsettings for awhile now.

Comment: You could consider using the [NLog Configuration API](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-API).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update NLog.Extension.Logging ver. 1.4.0**

With NLog.Extension.Logging ver. 1.4.0 then you can now use `${configsetting}`

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

**Original Answer**

With help from nuget-package [NLog.Appsettings.Standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Appsettings.Standard/) then you can normally do this:

```
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Appsettings.Standard" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Database" name="database"
          connectionString="${appsettings:name=DatabaseConfiguration.ConnectionString}"   
          commandText="INSERT INTO [SchemaOne].[EventLogs](Id, Message, Level, Logger )VALUES(NewID(), @Message, @Level, @Logger)">
      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
    </target>
  </targets>
```

But because you are using a special `dssettings.json` (instead of appsettings.json), then you probably have to implement your own custom NLog layout renderer:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

Maybe you can use the [source-code](https://github.com/linmasaki/NLog.Appsettings.Standard) from the above nuget-package as inspiration for loading `dssettings.json`. Or maybe create PullRequest that adds support for specifying non-default config-filename.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. Is it possible to have 2 appsettings.json then? So one dssettings.json and one appsettings.json

Comment: The `ConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile` can load from any filename. But like I said you have to implement the logic yourself. Maybe offer it as pull-request that allows one to provide custom filename.